# Unsupported or invalid disk type 2 for 'scsi0:0'. Ensure that the disk has been imported

Tags: virtualization, esxi, vmware-workstation

I just created a new virtual machine (kerio connect) on esxi 6.5 server from an existing .vmdk file.

when I try to start the virtual machine, I keep getting the following error:

> Unsupported or invalid disk type 2 for 'scsi0:0'. Ensure that the disk has been imported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the Virtual Device Node from SCSI controller 0 to IDE controller 0 at the hard disk settings of the virtual machine.

Comment: Perfect! The web is full of hints how to fix the "Unsupported and/or invalid disk type 7" error, but this is the only place that had the solution for "Unsupported and/or invalid disk type 2".

Comment: I agree with you. Haven't found a single topic about type 2 error. Maybe I didn't search proberly that time...

Comment: Just to detail it a bit more: I downloaded the VMX file from the ESXi datastore, opened it in Notepad (or similar) and replaced all occurrances of "`scsi0`" with "`ide0`", then uploaded the VMX again to the ESXi datastore. After that, the machine ran successfully.

Comment: It is also possible to fix it from web interface. 
Select VM -> Edit Settings -> Select HDD and unfold its settings -> change controller fro SCSI to IDE.  
good luck!

Comment: According to https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Worskstation-VM-disk-Type-2-Need-to-convert-to-Disk-Type-6-for/td-p/1422864 "type 2" is thinly provisioned. Unsure why VMware has problems with it, but it seems you can convert the image to fully provisioned.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone has also the same issue, check this article from Vmware. It solved for me:
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1028943

1. Connect to the ESX/ESXi host via SSH. I used Putty for that.
2. Run this command:

   ```
   vmkfstools -i <HostedVirtualDisk> <ESXVirtualDisk>
   ```

   Where `<HostedVirtualDisk>` is the path to the vmdk on the host and `<ESXVirtualDisk>` is the vmdk to be output by the command.

   For example:

   ```
   vmkfstools -i /vmfs/volumes/datastore/virtual_machine_folder/virtual_machine.vmdk /vmfs/volumes/datastore/new_virtual_machine_folder/virtual_machine.vmdk
   ```
3. Detach the currently attached VMDK from the virtual machine:

   1. In the vSphere Client or vSphere Web Client, right-click the virtual machine and click Edit Settings.
   2. Select the hard disk.
   3. Click Remove.
   4. Select the Remove from virtual machine option.
   5. Click OK.
4. Reattach the newly formatted VMDK from Step 2:

   1. In the vSphere Client or vSphere Web Client, right-click the virtual machine and click Edit Settings.
   2. Click Add.
   3. Select the hard disk.
   4. Click Next.
   5. Select the Use an existing virtual disk option.
   6. Click Next.
   7. Click Browse and locate the new VMDK created in Step 2.
   8. Click Next.
   9. Click Next.
   10. Click Finish to close the Add Hardware window.
   11. Click OK to close the Virtual Machine properties window.
5. Power on the virtual machine.

Comment: Was facing same issue, but when used `vmkfstools` observed that it expands the disk size to its limit even though disk was thin provisioned. Which may not be ideal always specially when disk limits are in `TB` size.

Comment: @ReddysekharGaduputi -d thin :-)